# Spring Boot not Autowiring datasource to DAO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Good afternoon, I am experiencing an issue where my spring application is not autowiring a Datasource to a DAO. The database is a postgresql db being ran on my local machine. I'm getting a null pointer exception in my userDAO where we try to execute datasource.getConnection, which is the error being caused when a certain endpoint of the api is requested. In the DatabaseConfig class method postgresDatasource, there is a commented out try catch block where I see if we still get thrown a null pointer exception if we attempt ds.getConnection. It does not throw an exception in there, event though that code is being ran at server build. Like I said, the error gets thrown when I assume that the autowiring is being execute corrected and we try datasource.getConnection. All relevant code will be pasted below. first is the DatabaseConfig class. It may be worth noting that my DatabaseConfig is in com.example.config, and the DAO is in com.example.dao

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
        ds.setUsername("username");
        ds.setPassword("password");
//      System.out.println("Returning ds object after setting parameters");
//      System.out.println(ds.toString());
//      try {
//          System.out.println("Attempting connection at server build.");
//          ds.getConnection();
//      } catch (SQLException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
        System.out.println("DataSource postgresDataSource() is being ran");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.fmn.config.DatabaseConfig;
import com.fmn.dto.UserDTO;

@Repository
public class UserDAO {

//  @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;
    
//  @Autowired
//  public void setDataSource(DataSource datasource) {
//      this.datasource = datasource;
//  }
//  
    @Autowired
    public UserDAO(DataSource datasource){
        System.out.println("Setting datasource in constructor");
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }
//  
    public UserDAO() {};

    public boolean addUser(UserDTO user) {
        //TODO: implement
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean updateUser(UserDTO user) {
        //TODO: implement
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public UserDTO getUserInfo(UserDTO user)/*throws UserNotFoundException*/ {
        //TODO: implement
        if(user.getUserId() != null) {
            return getUserInfoWithUserID(user);
        } else if (user.getEmail() != null) {
            return getUserInfoWithEmail(user);
        } else if (user.getPhoneNum() != null) {
            return getUserInfoWithPhone(user);
        }
        //else throw new UserNotFoundException();
        return null;
    }
    
    
    private UserDTO getUserInfoWithEmail(UserDTO user) {
        //TODO: implement
        return null;
    }
    
    private UserDTO getUserInfoWithPhone(UserDTO user) {
        //TODO: implement
        return null;
    }
    
    public UserDTO getUserInfoWithUserID(UserDTO user) {

        UserDTO outUser = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
//          DatabaseConfig dbc = new DatabaseConfig();
//          System.out.println("Setting datasource");
//          datasource = dbc.postgresDataSource();
            
            System.out.println("Calling datasource.getConnection()");
            conn = datasource.getConnection();
            CallableStatement caller = conn.prepareCall("{?= call get_user_info_with_userid(?)}");

            caller.registerOutParameter(1, Types.REF_CURSOR);
            caller.setString(2, user.getUserId());
            caller.execute();
            
            result = caller.getResultSet();
            result.next();
            
            outUser = setUserDTOFromResultSet(result);
            
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                
        return outUser;
    }

    private UserDTO setUserDTOFromResultSet(ResultSet result) throws SQLException {
        UserDTO outUser = new UserDTO();
        outUser.setDOB(result.getDate("DOB"));
        outUser.setUserId(result.getString("USER_ID"));
        outUser.setfName(result.getString("F_NAME"));
        outUser.setlName(result.getString("L_NAME"));
        outUser.setEmail(result.getString("EMAIL"));
        outUser.setAliveFlg(result.getString("ALIVE_FLG"));
        return outUser;
    }
    
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {DatabaseConfig.class, InteractiveController.class, UserDAO.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
         ctx.register(DatabaseConfig.class);
         ctx.refresh();
        
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Your feedback and input is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: why do you  have different ComponentScan annotations?

Comment: @Stultuske I didn't realize that.. I just changed the DatabaseConfig ComponentScan to ` @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses= {UserDAO.class}) `, still getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Don't reinvent what Boot provides; in particular, do not create your own application context (that's the entire point of Boot), don't create your own `DataSource` object, and _probably_ use Spring Data instead of writing DAOs. tl;dr start with a basic application from start.spring.io and try not to add _any_ `@Configuration` objects for now.